# sync.Map seems not safe concurrent read/write

Tags: go, concurrency

Test the sync.Map in golang standard package. It seems not safe concurrent read and write.
What's wrong?

Test code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var m sync.Map
    m.Store("count", 0)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for numOfThread := 0; numOfThread < 10; numOfThread++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
                value, ok := m.Load("count")
                if !ok {
                    log.Println("load count error")
                } else {
                    v, _ := value.(int)
                    m.Store("count", v+1)
                }
            }
        }()
    }

    log.Println("threads starts")
    wg.Wait()

    value, ok := m.Load("count")
    if ok {
        v, _ := value.(int)
        log.Printf("final count: %d", v)
    }

    log.Println("all done")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/E-pw4iZUceB

The result should be 10000, but get random number but not 10000:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 threads starts
2009/11/10 23:00:00 final count: 6696
2009/11/10 23:00:00 all done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a race condition:

```
 value, ok := m.Load("count")
 ...
 v, _ := value.(int)
 m.Store("count", v+1)
```

The read-modify-store above does not protect other goroutines do the same thing, thus some of the increments performed by other goroutines will be missed.

The sync.Map protects concurrent access to its members. That means, a write to the map will not cause other goroutines to read an inconsistent map. If you read-modify-write, nothing will protect other goroutines from updating the value at the same time. You need a mutex to protect access to the map when you read-modify-update.

Comment: Thank you, I got the point. So if I use sync.Map to store API request count for user, it should add extra mutex to protect the read-plusone-update cycle, I think it might reduce the performance, any mature solution for this scenario?

Comment: Use a regular map, `map[string]*uint64`, and use `sync/atomic` to increment the map value without any locks.

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var m sync.Map
    m.Store("count", 0)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var mu *sync.Mutex

    for numOfThread := 0; numOfThread < 10; numOfThread++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
                mu.Lock()
                value, ok := m.Load("count")
                if !ok {
                    log.Println("load count error")
                } else {
                    v, _ := value.(int)
                    m.Store("count", v+1)
                }
               mu.Unlock()
            }
        }()
    }

    log.Println("threads starts")
    wg.Wait()

    value, ok := m.Load("count")
    if ok {
        v, _ := value.(int)
        log.Printf("final count: %d", v)
    }

    log.Println("all done")
}
```

both read and write operation are thread safe, but you are attempting an upsert or read+write operation. It is not thread safe. Modified code to make it thread safe.

Comment: Yes this code will work with built in map type of golang. The reason for using sync.Map is to provide thread safe read or write, it does not provide thread safe read+write, as the original question stated.

Comment: ThinkGoodly's pt is, a `sync.Map` is redundant since the critical section is now protected by a `sync.Mutex`.

Comment: yes, i got it, using a sync.Map is not giving any benefit.